# Why Many to one relation defined entity return null result?

Tags: php, symfony4

I have following `many to one` relation in my 2 entities.

### Activity

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
 */
private $id;
```

### Booking

```
/**
 * @var Activity
 *
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Activity")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 * })
 */
private $type;
```

This is returning me following:

```
App\Entity\Booking {#841
  -id: 3
  -day: "2021-02-09"
  -type: Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Activity {#867
    +__isInitialized__: false
    -id: 10
    -activityName: null
    -status: null
     …2
  }
  -information: "dgdfg"
```

My other params except id are coming null.

What I have done wrong here.

Comment: This is due to lazy loading. When you try to get the object (call `getType` - I assume you have a getter - on a `Booking` instance), is it fully hydrated then?

Comment: Yes I have getType() inside Booking. So how can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Why do you think it's a problem? When you call `getType`, does your Activity object have all the necessary data?

Comment: When I call getType() , result got only ID filled, remaining other fields are null

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry. My bad. I forgot you need to call a property on the object for an actual hydration to take place. When you call `getActivityName` that object, does it return the actual data?

Comment: No it didn't return. It gave `Attempted to call an undefined method named`

Comment: Well, it seems like you don't have that getter defined in that class then. Try to access the property whichever way you normally would.